# Could not parse the remainder: ' .counter' from 'forloop .counter'

Tags: python, django

```
< h1 > {{ question.question_text }} </ h1 >

{% if error_message %} < p >< strong > {{ error_message }} </ strong ></ p > {% endif %}

<form action = " {% url 'polls:vote' question.id %} " method = "post" >
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <% input type = "radio" name = "choice" id = "choice {{ forloop .counter }} " value = " {{ choice.id }} "% >
    < label for = "choice {{ forloop .counter }} " > {{ choice.choice_text }} </ label >< br >
{% endfor %}
< input type = "submit" value = "Vote" >
</form >
```

I have this error running the command: python manage.py `runserver`

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ' .counter' from 'forloop .counter'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Remove the space before the dot. It should be `{{ forloop.counter }}` not `{{ forloop .counter }}`

Comment: Thanks, but now the error is: 'polls is not a registered namespace'

Comment: i changed "< form action = " {% url 'polls:vote' question.id %} " method = "post" >" to :< form action = " {% url 'vote' question.id %} " method = "post" > and it's correct :) . thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working. Your other option is to add `app_name = 'polls'` to `polls/urls.py`. Then `{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}` will work.